# How to make a square that changes colors when the user presses some keys?

Tags: c++, opengl

I wrote a code, but I don't know where it went wrong. Can somebody help me with that?

I wrote some comments in my code. If someone could help me I'd be very glad.
Because I can't find the error by myself. :(

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

// Function callback that is called to draw
void Desenha(void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Clean the window
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Shows that the color is red
    //         R     G     B
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Draw a square
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(30,226);
    glVertex2i(226,30);
    // Shows that the color is blue
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2i(30,226);
    glVertex2i(226,30);
    glEnd();

    // Executes the OpenGL's commands
    glFlush();
}

// rendering
void Inicializa (void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

void AlteraTamanhoJanela(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    // Evita a divisao por zero
    if(h == 0) h = 1;

    // Especifica as dimensões da Viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Inicializa o sistema de coordenadas
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // (left, right, bottom, top)
    if (w <= h)
        gluOrtho2D (0.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f, 250.0f*h/w);
    else
        gluOrtho2D (0.0f, 250.0f*w/h, 0.0f, 250.0f);
}

// Function callback that is called to manage the keyboard tasks
void GerenciaTeclado(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 97:
    case 'a':// change the actual color to red
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        break;
    case 118:
    case 'v':// change de color do blue
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        break;
    case 27:
    case 'esc':// close the screen
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Main Program
int main(void)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(256,256);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutCreateWindow("Quadrado");
    glutDisplayFunc(Desenha);
    glutReshapeFunc(AlteraTamanhoJanela);
    Inicializa();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: "I don't know where it went wrong" is not very helpful. Please describe exactly what happens and what should happen for some example input.

Comment: That is a lot of code (and in Portuguese), and its difficult to tell what it does without being more familiar with all the other methods you are calling.  Could you take some time to pick out only the most relevant pieces of code, and give some more details about what the problem is?

Comment: It looks like you are changing the color via glColor3f when the user presses a key, but the color is changed again in your draw (Desenha) function.

Comment: [For the mono-lingual (i.e. me).](https://translate.google.co.uk/?hl=en&tab=wT&authuser=0#auto/en/desenha%0AInicializa%0AAltera%20Tamanho%20Janela%0AGerencia%20Teclado)

Comment: I'm having some troubles with my C++ code and I really don't know where it went wrong. 
It was expected to draw a square and change the color when the user press some keys. The window's background should be white and as the user press the keys the color of the square should change from red to blue and when the user press the key again the color should go back to red as you can see it with the code. Does anyone know why I can't compile it?

Answer (score 1):

Among other things your `switch()` didn't compile, you were missing a `glutInit()` call, and you never hooked up `GerenciaTeclado()` via `glutKeyboardFunc()`.

Try this:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

// Function callback that is called to manage the keyboard taks
float r = 0.0f;
float g = 0.0f;
float b = 0.0f;
void GerenciaTeclado(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 'a':// change the actual color to red
        r = 1.0f;
        g = 0.0f;
        b = 0.0f;
        break;
    case 'v':// change de color do blue
        r = 0.0f;
        g = 0.0f;
        b = 1.0f;
        break;
    case 27:// close the screen
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Function callback that is called to draw
void Desenha(void)
{
    // Clean the window
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Inicializa o sistema de coordenadas
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    glOrtho( -2 * ar, 2 * ar, -2, 2, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Draw a square
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Shows that the color is red
    //        R  G  B
    glColor3f(r, g, b);
    glVertex2f(-1, -1);
    glVertex2f( 1, -1);
    // Shows that the color is blue
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f( 1, 1);
    glVertex2f(-1, 1);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// Main Program
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(256,256);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutCreateWindow("Quadrado");
    glutDisplayFunc(Desenha);
    glutKeyboardFunc(GerenciaTeclado);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```